# How to allow the user to turn off proxy settings with GPO?

Tags: group-policy

I want to create a policy that allows users on laptops to be able to turn on/off the proxy settigns.

So if they are home on their home WiFI, they can turn off proxy settings. While at work, they can turn it back on.

If we can automate

Comment: I can't find the option in GPMC. I wanted them to be able to turn it on or off when needed

Comment: These pcs will only be used when connected to the domain, if not, setting the group policy on a non-domain connected pc is sort of pointless

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a WPAD (Web Proxy Auto-Discovery) file on your corporate network.

Once this is configured, the computers will be able to automatically detect the proxy settings (and in your GPO you can set Internet Explorer to "Automatically detect the proxy settings").

More details about how to configure WPAD here:
http://findproxyforurl.com/deploying-wpad/